# continuously writing to csv file in a loop

Tags: python, csv

With my full script I'm comparing the tweets of 90 companies with the tweets of their followers, and the tweets of followers of the other companies. I'm trying to write all the results into one csv file, but I'm not sure how to do that in a loop. Right now the most important part of the code looks like this:

```
for x in tweets_companies:
    for y in tweets_followers:
        D1 = " ".join([tweets_companies[x]])
        D2 = " ".join([tweets_followers[y]])
        documents = [D1, D2]

        LemVectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
        tf_matrix = LemVectorizer.transform(documents)#.toarray()
        tfidfTran = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
        tfidfTran.fit(tf_matrix)

        print(x,y)
        tfidf_matrix = tfidfTran.transform(tf_matrix)
        cos_similarity_matrix = (tfidf_matrix * tfidf_matrix.T).toarray()

        print(cos_similarity_matrix)
```

this results in the following result each time a company's tweets is compared to the tweets of either their own followers, or followers of another company:

```
company_a followers_b
[[1.        0.2745773]
 [0.2745773 1.       ]]
```

This loop keeps printing the results until for each company, their tweets have been compared to the tweets of the followers of each other company. I'm trying to write all results into one csv file, but I'm not sure how that works with this loop. Right now, I've got the following:

```
  results = [x, y, cos_similarity_matrix]
  with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
      writer.writerow(['company', 'followers', 'result'])
      writer.writerow(results)
```

I've placed this in the second 'for' loop, and right now it only writes the last results it prints in python into the csv file. How do I make sure that the csv file is updated with newly printed results each time, so that in the end all the results of each company are placed into the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file every time inside the second loop. The file always has the same name and overwrites the previous file.  Move the

```
  with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
```

outside the outer loop and just write the rows in the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

Put the

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['company', 'followers', 'result'])
```

outside (above) the loop, and call `writer.writerow` inside the loop. The loop must be inside the `with` block.